# Javax.Json Cannot be resolved after upgrade to Eclipse Neon

Tags: java, json, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

I recently have downloaded the last Eclipse version, Neon for JEE, so i run it and i decide accept the advice from Eclipse and overwrite my workspace settings.

Then, when i opened my new brand Eclipse, what i found was my maven projects getting an error

> The import javax.Json cannot be resolved

I am using JRE 1.8 and a Wildfly 10.0 Runtime. Everithing else is fine: the jsvax.sevlet and javax.ejb APIs work.

Why Eclipse has removed (if that was what happened) the `javax.json` lib from my project libs? Any idea?

I attached my POM below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>xxx</groupId>
  <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>xxx</version>
  <name>Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.39</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency> 
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>onebrain</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your *pom.xml* file [`javax.json` dependency](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax.json%7Cjavax.json-api%7C1.0%7Cbundle). Maybe in previous installed Eclipse version, you added this library manually in Eclipse project built path settings.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure i did not. Actually, i created the project on a  fresh and clean eclipse installation! I know i could add the javax.json dependency to my POM, but i am going to keep asking me why happened what happened. Have the eclipse default behavior changed in this last version, maybe? (By the way thanks for ur answer)

Comment: @JotaUribe Maybe in previous Eclipse version you create default JavaEE project and that default project include `javax` library in build path.

Answer (score 0):

In general it is good idea to have explicitly declared all used dependencies independently on classpath or eclipse settings.
It is very useful to check your pom.xml time to time with *[Maven Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html)*:

```
mvn dependency:analyze
```

It shows you witch dependencies are you using without having them declared - just handing on transitive dep which can surprise you in the future when you change version of some dependency and other one can be gone.